# Web server HttpListener response

Tags: c#, http, webserver, httplistenerrequest

I have some problems with displaying HttpListenerResponse in correct way.
I am using http://www.codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx as a sample! I want to display "1.html" but I can not!When I display it in my browser it display well. When I try to display as a response it displays with out image girl.png

code of **"1.html"**

```
    <HTML>
        <BODY>
            My web page.<br> 
            <p>
              <img src="girl.png" width="189" height="255" alt="lorem">
              <input id="btnLogin" type="button" value="login"  " style="width:100px;" />
            </p>
        </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

**WebServer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleWebServer
{
    public class WebServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener = new HttpListener();
        private readonly Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> _responderMethod;

        public WebServer(string[] prefixes, Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
                throw new NotSupportedException(
                    "Needs Windows XP SP2, Server 2003 or later.");

            // URI prefixes are required, for example 
            // "http://localhost:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // A responder method is required
            if (method == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("method");

            foreach (string s in prefixes)
                _listener.Prefixes.Add(s);

            _responderMethod = method;
            _listener.Start();
            _listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), _listener);
        }
        private static void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;
            listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);
            Console.WriteLine("New request.");

            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;


            byte[] page = GetFile("1.html");

            response.ContentLength64 = page.Length;
            Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(page, 0, page.Length);
            output.Close();


        }
        public static byte[] GetFile(string file)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(file)) return null;
            FileStream readIn = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 1000];
            int nRead = readIn.Read(buffer, 0, 10240);
            int total = 0;
            while (nRead > 0)
            {
                total += nRead;
                nRead = readIn.Read(buffer, total, 10240);
            }
            readIn.Close();
            byte[] maxresponse_complete = new byte[total];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, maxresponse_complete, 0, total);
            return maxresponse_complete;
        }

        public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> method, params string[] prefixes)
            : this(prefixes, method) { }

        public void Run()
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((o) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Webserver running...");
                try
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((c) =>
                        {
                            var ctx = c as HttpListenerContext;
                            try
                            {
                                string rstr = _responderMethod(ctx.Request);
                                byte[] buf = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rstr);
                                ctx.Response.ContentLength64 = buf.Length;
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                            }
                            catch { } // suppress any exceptions
                            finally
                            {
                                // always close the stream
                                ctx.Response.OutputStream.Close();
                            }
                        }, _listener.GetContext());
                    }
                }
                catch { } // suppress any exceptions
            });
        }
            public void Stop()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
            _listener.Close();
        }
    }    }
```

Code in main Form

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://localhost:8080/test/");
            ws.Run();
            Console.WriteLine("A simple webserver. Press a key to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            ws.Stop();
        }
        public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}   <p><input type='submit' value='Отправить'></BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);            }
```

How display my 1.html as in browser?

Comment: Try not suppressing exceptions. If something is wrong, you will not know what.

Answer (score 2):

When I look at your code, the first thing I see is that your image is referenced with a relative path.
If you stream the HTML code to another server, it cannot find the image if it isn't there on the other end in that relative location.

Use a full URL reference (e.g. http://otherserver.com/girl.png) to the image and it should be accessible.

Comment: I am sorry but FoxHound is wrong! client connect to web server and as a response server send html page to client!

Comment: Normally a HTML file is no more than text and the image isn't part of the page itself. The image is only something that is retrieved externally and shown in the page. Something else that has caught my eye: Your SendResponse function returns a fixed string, which is almost the same as your file, minus the image tag.

Comment: I've put your code in a small test application and it does seem that the html that is returned to the browser, just can't find the image.
The Webserver you have there is very basic and it only returns the html page, nothing more, which then get's interpreted by the browser. Because the browser never recieves any image data, nor can it find it in it's working folder, it cannot show the image in place and "Lorem" is displayed. BTW, you should add "response.ContentType = "text/html";" to your ListenerCallback function so your browser knows it's html it's receiving